# Show that $|\Bbb Z_n^*|$ is even if $n\ge 3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that $|\Bbb Z_n^*|$ (i.e the elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ relatively prime to n forming a group under multiplication) is even if $n \ge 3$ using a corollary in my textbook to Lagrange's theorem that states that the order of any element divides the order of the group.

I realize this is related to the euler totient function but is there another way to show this using only elementary group theory concepts?

Answer (score 0):

If $n\geq 3$, $1\neq -1\equiv n-1 \mod n$. Note that $H=\{-1,1\}$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^{*}$. Thus, by the Corollary of Lagrange's theorem that you mentioned, $|H|=2$ divides $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, and so the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ is even.